# How to align Bootstrap card row to bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make the bottom rows on my Bootstrap cards to line up. Using `position: absolute;` works but I then get overlapping text on small screens. In this example the first and third card icon rows should line up when they are all side by side in a row. Instead they are positioned directly under the card content.

[image: screenshot]

```
<div class="container-flex m-2">
    <ul class="row list-group list-group-horizontal align-items-stretch flex-wrap">
    
        
        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100 justify-content-between">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text h-100">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary"mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                        <div/>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。 まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary"mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                        <div/>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
            
        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-text">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary"mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                        <div/>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list-group-item {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1% !important;
    padding: 0; !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .list-group-item {
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 47%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .list-group-item {
        
        width: 31.333%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at using card-group or card-deck with footers https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-layout

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to keep the same responsive layout. The alignment seems to break when I use the viewport method with footers for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `d-flex flex-column` tp card-body and `h-100` to card-text

```css
.list-group-item {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1% !important;
    padding: 0; !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .list-group-item {
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .list-group-item {
        width: 47%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .list-group-item {
        
        width: 31.333%;
        margin: 5px 1% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<div class="container-flex m-2">
    <ul class="row list-group list-group-horizontal align-items-stretch flex-wrap">

        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100 justify-content-between">
                <div class="card-body  d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-text h-100">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary">mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                      </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-text h-100">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。 まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary">mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                     </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
            
        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-text h-100">
                        <p>まず 、 顔 は 正面 を 向いた まま 、 耳 と 肩 を 近づける ように 頭 を 横  に  倒します 。</p>
                        <p class="text-secondary">mazu, kao wa shoumen o muita mama, mimi to kata o chikadukeru youni atama wo yoko ni taoshimasu.</p>
                        <p>First, turn your head sideways, with your face facing you and your ears and shoulders close together.</p>
                        </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"><i class='fab fa-youtube pr-3' style='font-size:24px'></i><i class='fas fa-volume-up' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                    <div class="col text-right"><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:24px'></i></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```